# Battery indicator shows "not charging" when the battery is full, and a battery percentage when charging

Tags: power-management, laptop, indicator, battery, 19.10

Since my upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10, the battery indicator shows "not charging" when the charger is plugged in while the battery is full. This could be correct but confusing.
When the battery is not completely full and charging, it shows only the remaining battery life and percentage as if it was running from the battery.

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853666 , I'd suggest having a look and if that applies, click "*affects me too*" and add a comment at the bottom with your system details (adding click me & details will add heat & more information that may help get it fixed)